# Must declare the scalar variable "@id"

Tags: sqlexception

I know this question has been asked like a thousandth time. But the solutions given do not work for me.
I have a very simple stored procedure like below:

`alter procedure sp_updateVacancyWithRecruitment
(@id int,
@idList varchar(100)
)
as
EXEC('update Vacancy_team1 set recruitment_request_id=@id where id IN ('+@idList +')')`

And even the following doesn't work :

`exec sp_updateVacancyWithRecruitment @id=5,@idList='6,8'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Must declare the scalar variable “@id”` This is the error I get.

Comment: that's not a question. How do you expect anyone to help you if you don't provide sufficient information? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to update column `recruitment_request_id` in the table `Vacancy_team1` with the value in `@id` where the values in column `id` is equal to the given `@idList` . But each time I try to run this : `exec sp_updateVacancyWithRecruitment @id=5,@idList='6,8'` , I get this error : `Must declare the scalar variable “@id”` .

Comment: BTW you're code `('+@idList+')'` appears to have a [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) problem.  Careful with that code.

Comment: That's taken care of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK . Got it . Syntax error. My bad.
The correct procedure is :
`alter procedure sp_updateVacancyWithRecruitment
(@id int,
@idList varchar(100)
)
as
EXEC('update Vacancy_team1 set recruitment_request_id='+@id+' where id IN ('+@idList+')')`